# Сравнение строчки в ComboBox WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

При нажатии на элемент "1.11.X" в ComboBox, программа вылетает, что делать?

```
    private void ComboBoxFunc_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var directory = @"C:\@TempDownload\";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        if ((String)Huzumi.SelectedItem == "1.11.X")
        {
            wc.DownloadFile("ССЫЛКА", directory);
            Process.Start("explorer", directory);
        }
    }
```

Ошибка вот тут походу. Пробовал не только SelectedItem.

> if ((String)Huzumi.SelectedItem == "1.11.X")

Comment: Куда программа вылетает?

Comment: Никуда. Ошибка вот такая. Приложение перешло в состояние останова,

Comment: На какой строке вылетает? Какая ошибка? Дополните свой вопрос этими данными.

Comment: Кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/769066/edit) пожалуйста в вопрос.

Comment: @Bulson , if ((String)Huzumi.SelectedItem == "1.11.X")

Comment: А что пишет в сообщении об ошибке?

Comment: @Bulson , Приложение перешло в состояние останова.

Comment: И это всё? Там обычно еще кое-чего написано...

Comment: @Bulson Приложение перешло в состояние останова, но отсутствует код для вывода на экран, так как все потоки исполняли внешний код (как правило, системный код или код платформы).

Comment: В таких случаях делают так: выносят в переменную `string str = (String)Huzumi.SelectedItem; ` ставят на эту строку точку останова, запускают, делаю шаг к след. инструкц. и смотрят чему равно значение переменной `str` и сравнивают с тем, что желают видеть. Чешут репу, кумекают, исправляют... или спрашивают здесь, с подробными пояснениями о том, что получается, а что хотят в итоге получить.

Comment: Не похоже на ошибку в коде: дебаггер бы показал проблему в конкретной строке. Какая-то ошибка в самом WPF и нужно это исключение поймать. Сделать это можно так: https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/06/25/1101-defining-a-handler-for-unhandled-exceptions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как надо было, сложно было просто чуть поправить?)

```
private void ComboBoxDownloadFunc_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBoxDownloadFunc.Text) && ComboBoxDownloadFunc.Text == "1.11.X")
        {
            // #### Действие. #### //
        }
    }
```